# Как сделать резиновый блок, если дочерние элементы имеют свойства top/left

Tags: css

Всем привет, проблема в следующем:

1) В родительский блок вставляются дочерние, дочерние содержат картинки, на этом этапе высота родительского блока стала `900px`.

2) После загрузки картинок, дочерние блоки выравниваются специальным образом с помощью [jquery-ui.position()](http://api.jqueryui.com/position/). Дочерние элементы легли как надо, плотно, но высота родительского блока по прежнему `900px`, хотя дочерние элементы занимают в 2 раза меньше места.

3) Я пришёл к выводу, что это из-за того, что дочерние элементы, после выравнивания с помощью [jquery-ui.position()](http://api.jqueryui.com/position/) получают свойства `left` и `top`. Если убрать отключить позиционирование, то родитель ресайзится как надо.

Как сделать высоту блока резиновой по отношению к содержимому, если дочерние блоки выстроены с помощью свойств `left`/`top`?

```html
<div class='content'>
    <div class='item'></div>
    <div class='item'></div>
    <div class='item'></div>
    <div class='item'></div>
</div>
```

Cтили:

```css
.content{
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100%;
    position:relative;
    display: block;
    height: auto;
    padding: 0;
}

.item{
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Код:

```js
              SFW.prototype._fillCollection = function(way){
                var _this = this;

                /*тот самый родитель, который не ресайзится*/
                var content = $('<div class="content"></div>')
                    .appendTo(this.viewBlock)
                    .data('count', 0);
   
                var items = this._data[way.firstLevel].items[way.secondLevel].items;

                var elements = [];
                
                /*дети*/
                for(var k = 0; k < items.length; k+=1) {
                    var wrapItem = $('<div class="item"></div>')
                        .appendTo(content)
                        .data('data', items[k]);
                    var item = $("<img>")
                        .data('data', items[k])
                        .attr("src", items[k].PICTURE_FACE)
                        .appendTo(wrapItem)
                        .load(function(){
                            _this._waitAllImg(content);
                         });
                    elements.push(wrapItem);
                }
                
                content.data('elements', elements);
            };

            /*ждём загрузки изображений*/
            SFW.prototype._waitAllImg = function(content){
                content.data('count', content.data('count') + 1);
                if(content.data('count') === content.data('elements').length){
                    this._regularizeImg(content);
                }
            };

            /*упорядочивание детей*/
            SFW.prototype._regularizeImg = function(content){
                var elements = content.data('elements');
                for(var i = 0; i < elements.length; i +=1){
                    var of, my, at, elem, data;

                    elem = elements[i];
                    data = elem.data('data');
           
                    of = data.of;
                    my = data.my;
                    at = data.at;
                 
/*Если закомментировать строчку ниже,то дочерние элементы добавляются конечно не так как надо, зато родитель меняет свой размер под содержимое*/
                    elements[i].position({my: my, at: at, of: of});
                }
            };
```

P.S. мне нужно это для того, что бы в свою очередь родителей выстроить друг за другом, списком, а так получается, что в конце каждого нового родителя пустое место.

Comment: Прикреплю скрин http://i.imgur.com/bVH928F.png

Comment: Почему высота 900.если у вас в коде она авто?!И как элементы child могут выравниваться с помощью позиций,если у блока стоит релатив?!Можете js код показать?

Comment: Зашел на ссылку, что вы указали.Здесь высота родительского-задается не js,высота сразу прописана через css.И если у него поставить высоту-авто.То все норм становится. http://s020.radikal.ru/i713/1511/23/6b821025502c.png

Comment: HoPkInS, высота становится 900 из-за первоначального расположения детей, до позиционирования. 900 - это цифра, которую мне показывает DevTools, height по прежнему стоит auto. top и left работают, если текущий и дочерний элементы relative: http://htmlbook.ru/css/top. Код сейчас добавлю в пост

Comment: Проблему решил пересчитав вручную на Js высоту блока. Но вопрос остался.